# Unable to add custom app in bitnami nginx stack install on windows

Tags: php, nginx, bitnami

I just installed Bitnami nginx/MySql/php stack on windows 7. I started off with the documentation from this link http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/Bitnami_Nginx_Stack

Everything works fine but i'm unable to add any custom php app. I have tried it with the demo app provided with the package. App is located in " C:/Bitnami/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/apps/ " directory as suggested. Below are the contents of Nginx confs files:

Nginx/conf/Bitnami-apps-prefix.conf

```
include "C:/Bitnami/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/nginx-prefix.conf";
include "C:/Bitnami/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/apps/demo/conf/nginx-prefix.conf";
```

apps/demo/Nginx-prefix.conf: (demo is apps name)

```
location /demo {
    alias "C:/Bitnami/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/apps/demo/htdocs";    
    include "C:/Bitnami/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/apps/demo/conf/nginx-app.conf";
}
```

There is also phpmyadmin app and its working fine with localhost in my browser. but demo app shows a 404 error. I have rechecked many times and restarted nginx too but nothing works. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "/Applications/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/nginx/conf/bitnami" folder and edit bitnami-apps-prefix.conf.
Copy and Paste include "/Applications/nginxstack-1.6.2-1/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/nginx-prefix.conf"; and replace "phpmyadmin" with your custom app name.